# Addition of MS Planner to modern SharePoint page disturbing the SharePoint list in the page

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, sharepoint-list, microsoft-planner

I am working on the modern SharePoint Online. I have added a new page and linked couple of SharePoint list. When I am adding the MS Planner to same page, it is disturbing the look and feel of table. it is creating big dots on each column header. I have included the screen shot for ready reference.
**Q: is it possible to remove these color dots?**

[image]

Comment: I did the test and also got a lot of green dots on the list. According to my research, there's no way to remove these green dots for the time being.

Comment: I am not expert in this area, but i am curious to know what is leading to cause this?